# If $N$ and $K$ are normal subgroups of a group $G$ such that $G=MN$ and $M\cap N=\langle e \rangle$ then $G=M\times N$.

Tags: group-theory, notation, permutations, products

The following is an exercise in Hungerford's abstract algebra text.

If $N$ and $K$ are normal subgroups of a group $G$ such that $G=MN$ and $M\cap N=\langle e \rangle$ then $G=M\times N$.

If $G=S_3$ with $N=\langle (123) \rangle,$ and $N=\langle (12)\rangle,$ with $N$ as not being normal, then the conclusion to the above statement would not hold.  However, for finite permutation groups, say $G$ is a finite permutation group.  If it is possible to write $G$ as an external direct product of its subgroups $P,Q$ (and assuming such can be done), then for any $\sigma\in G,$ $\sigma=(\sigma_1, \sigma_2)\in P\times Q?$  The reason I am asking is because I was never told when we take product of permutations, is that consider an external direct product.  But notationally, when talking about external direct product, we use $n-$tuple notation $(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$ instead of $a_1a_2a_3\cdots a_n$

Thank you in advance

Comment: It is not clear from what you write exactly what you are asking. What is your question? (There is not "?" sign anywhere in your post!)

Comment: How do you define the direct product? Because some authors define it as the property you're supposing . . .

Comment: This ia reaction to this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4668477/let-n-k-be-subgroups-of-a-group-g-with-n-unlhd-g-if-n-and-k-are-abe

Comment: @NickyHekster in Hungerford's text, there are a series of three questions relating to knocking out conditions to two of the theorems presented in the text and also another exercise which all three use $S_3$ as a counterexample.  In the process of trying to figure out why $S_3$ would serve as a counter example.  The thought of how to write the external direct product of of subgroups of $S_n$ notationally, how it is written notationally was never presented in the text, and also does ordinary multiplication of elements of elements of permutation groups consider external direct product.

Comment: @DerekHolt in Hungerford's text, there are a series of three questions relating to knocking out conditions to two of the theorems presented in the text and also another exercise which all three use $S_3$ as a counterexample.  In the process of trying to figure out why $S_3$ would serve as a counter example.  The thought of how to write the external direct product of of subgroups of $S_n$ notationally, how it is written notationally was never presented in the text, and also does ordinary multiplication of elements of elements of permutation groups consider external direct product.

Comment: @Shaun since we are talking about finite permutation groups, I am assuming that the external and internal direct product to be the same, or is that too much to ask in terms of assumptions?

Comment: Are you confusing cycle notation with ordered pairs? It truly is impossible to figure out what your question is. Are you asking why $S_3$ is not isomorphic to a cyclic group of order $6$?

Comment: @TedShifrin basically I am asking if multiplying in cycle notation, where elements are from different subgroups of $S_n$, then can that be consider as a direct product of some sort.  Because if $G=S_n$ and $G=N\times K$ where both $N,K$ are subgroups of $G$, then what does that look like notationally in terms of elements of $N,K$?

Comment: @TedShifrin I did not know you are still active on MSE.  I want to thank you so very much for making your advance calculus videos series, it was because of them that I was able to get through my course in Calculus on Manifolds.

Comment: The cycles must be disjoint so that they commute. If you have disjoint cycles, then the direct product of the cyclic subgroups they generate will beca subgroup.  LOL … I’m glad the videos helped you.

Comment: @TedShifrin my second year calculus course was baby Spivak/Munkres, we took it without any background in general topology.   Depending on who is teaching it, some prof even went so far as deRham cohomology at that course's end after generalized stokes theorem.  Some grad student who took the course had to relearn vector calculus on their own so that they can teach their assigned course.

Comment: @TedShifrin Also, thank you for the clarification.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isomorphism: $\phi(g) = \phi(mn) = (m,n) \in M \times N$.

Multiplication in $M \times N$:
$$(m_1,n_1) \times (m_2,n_2) = (m_1m_2,m_2^{-1}n_1m_2n_2)$$

$$\phi(m_1n_1m_2n_2) = \phi(m_1m_2m_2^{-1}n_1m_2 n_2) = (m_1m_2,m_2^{-1}n_1m_2 n_2)$$

$$\phi(m_1n_1) \times \phi(m_2n_2) = (m_1,n_1) \times (m_2,n_2) = (m_1m_2,m_2^{-1}n_1m_2n_2) = \phi(m_1n_1m_2n_2)$$

Hence $\phi$ is a homomorphism.

$\phi$ is injective:
$\phi(m_1n_1) = (m_1,n_1) = (e,e) \implies m_1 = e, n_1 = e$

$\phi$ is clearly surjective.

Well definedness:
$m_1n_1 = m_2 n_2 \implies$ $m_1 = m_2$ and $n_1 = n_2$ since $M \cap N = \{e\}$.

Hence $\phi$ is an isomorphism and $MN \approx M \times N$. But here the multiplication in $M \times N$ is defined same as semi-direct product of $M$ and $N$. So technically $MN$ is isomorphic to semi-direct product of $M$ and $N$.

Comment: thank you so much for your detail answer.  I did not know what I was asking is about the semidirect product.  There is this huge fog that has not been lifted over my brain.  :)